# SQL Updating records based on most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-update, updates

I am trying to update two fields (`UNIT_COST`) from (`LST_RECV_COST`) and `VEND_ITEM_NO`) from same filed (`VEND_ITEM_NO`).

All fields in one table (`PO_VEND_ITEM`). The table has sequence rows sorted by date filed (`LST_RECV_DAT`).

I want to update the data with record in the most recent date row.
I have used the following code

```
UPDATE
PO_VEND_ITEM
SET
UNIT_COST = LST_RECV_COST,
VEND_ITEM_NO = VEND_ITEM_NO,
WHERE
LST_RECV_DAT = (SELECT MAX(LST_RECV_DAT)
```

It always get any error message. I am new to sql and do not know which code can work.

Could you advise please?

Comment: Why did you want to update the same column `VEND_ITEM_NO`?

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax mistakes.

Try this.

```
UPDATE PO_VEND_ITEM
SET UNIT_COST    = LST_RECV_COST,
    VEND_ITEM_NO = VEND_ITEM_NO
WHERE LST_RECV_DAT = (SELECT MAX(LST_RECV_DAT) FROM PO_VEND_ITEM)
```

Answer (score 0):

use below `DML` to update table based on `max()` field

```
update PO_VEND_ITEM
set UNIT_COST = LST_RECV_COST   
from
    (select max(LST_RECV_DAT) LST_RECV_DAT, 
    VEND_ITEM_NO from PO_VEND_ITEM
    group by VEND_ITEM_NO) t1
where VEND_ITEM_NO = t1.VEND_ITEM_NO and t1.LST_RECV_DAT = LST_RECV_DAT
```